# Deploying VS2012 web deploy package fails due to trying to delete itself

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, asp.net-web-api

I created a Single Page Application using VS 2012/.net 4.5. I wanted to try to host it locally in IIS, and thus decided to deploy it.

I followed the steps here for creating a web deploy package: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx

And the steps here for installing that deployment package:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff356104(v=vs.110).aspx

For the most part it seemed pretty simple. Very little configuration, and when deploying I just had to run the command.

When running in trial mode (/T) the deployment indicates that it completes successfully. However it fails when run in update mode (/Y) because the deployment is seemingly trying to delete the package file before it has fully deployed the everything from with in it.

Run in Update mode:

```
C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr\
Deploy>MomConfigMgr.deploy.cmd /Y
SetParameters from:
"C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr
\Deploy\MomConfigMgr.SetParameters.xml"
You can change IIS Application Name, Physical path, connectionString
or other deploy parameters in the above file.
-------------------------------------------------------
 Start executing msdeploy.exe
-------------------------------------------------------
 "C:\Program Files\IIS\Microsoft Web Deploy V3\msdeploy.exe" -source:package='C:
\Users\Declan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr\De
ploy\MomConfigMgr.zip' -dest:auto,includeAcls="False" -verb:sync -disableLink:Ap
pPoolExtension -disableLink:ContentExtension -disableLink:CertificateExtension -
setParamFile:"C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MomConfigMgr
\MomConfigMgr\Deploy\MomConfigMgr.SetParameters.xml"
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Areas).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\HelpPage.css).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\Api.cshtml).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates)
.
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\ApiGr
oup.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\HelpP
ageApiModel.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\Image
Sample.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\Inval
idSample.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\Param
eters.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\Sampl
es.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\DisplayTemplates\TextS
ample.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Help\Index.cshtml).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Shared).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Shared\_Layout.cshtml).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\Web.config).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Areas\HelpPage\Views\_ViewStart.cshtml).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\Antlr3.Runtime.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\App_global.asax.compiled).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\App_global.asax.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\de).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\de\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\de\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\de\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.AspNet.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.Core.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.Consumer.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\EntityFramework.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\es).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\es\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\es\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\es\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\fr).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\fr\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\fr\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\fr\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\it).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\it\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\it\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\it\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\ja).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ja\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ja\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ja\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\ko).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ko\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ko\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ko\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\Microsoft.Data.OData.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\Microsoft.Web.Mvc.FixedDisplayModes.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\MomConfigMgr.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\Newtonsoft.Json.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\ru).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ru\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ru\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\ru\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Spatial.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Helpers.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Http.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Http.OData.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Http.Tracing.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Mvc.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Optimization.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.Razor.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.WebPages.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\System.Web.WebPages.Razor.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\WebGrease.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\WebMatrix.Data.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\WebMatrix.WebData.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hans).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hans\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hans\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).

Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hans\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hant).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hant\Microsoft.Data.Edm.resources.dll).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hant\Microsoft.Data.OData.resources.dll).

Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\bin\zh-Hant\System.Spatial.resources.dll).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Content).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\Site.css).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_0_aaaaaa_4
0x100.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_flat_75_ffffff_
40x100.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_55_fbf9ee
_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_65_ffffff
_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_dadada
_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_75_e6e6e6
_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_glass_95_fef1ec
_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-bg_highlight-soft_
75_cccccc_1x100.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_222222_256x2
40.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_2e83ff_256x2
40.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_454545_256x2
40.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_888888_256x2
40.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\images\ui-icons_cd0a0a_256x2
40.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery-ui.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.accordion.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.all.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.autocomplete.css).

Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.base.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.button.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.core.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.datepicker.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.dialog.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.progressbar.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.resizable.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.selectable.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.slider.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.tabs.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\jquery.ui.theme.css).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_flat_0
_aaaaaa_40x100.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_flat_7
5_ffffff_40x100.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_glass_
55_fbf9ee_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_glass_
65_ffffff_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_glass_
75_dadada_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_glass_
75_e6e6e6_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_glass_
95_fef1ec_1x400.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-bg_highli
ght-soft_75_cccccc_1x100.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-icons_222
222_256x240.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-icons_2e8
3ff_256x240.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-icons_454
545_256x240.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-icons_888
888_256x240.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\images\ui-icons_cd0
a0a_256x240.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery-ui.min.css).

Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.accordion
.min.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.autocompl
ete.min.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.button.mi
n.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.core.min.
css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.datepicke
r.min.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.dialog.mi
n.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.progressb
ar.min.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.resizable
.min.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.selectabl
e.min.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.slider.mi
n.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.tabs.min.
css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\themes\base\minified\jquery.ui.theme.min
.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Content\TodoList.css).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\favicon.ico).
Info: Adding directory (MomConfigMgr\Images).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\accent.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\bullet.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\heroAccent.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList0.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList1.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList2.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList3.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList4.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList5.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList6.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList7.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList8.png).
Info: Adding file (MomConfigMgr\Images\orderedList9.png).
Info: Deleting file (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.deploy-readme.txt).
Info: Deleting file (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.deploy.cmd).
Info: Deleting file (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.SetParameters.xml).
Info: Deleting file (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.SourceManifest.xml).
Info: Deleting file (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.zip).
Warning: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on 'Mo
mConfigMgr.zip'.
Retrying operation 'Delete' on object filePath (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.zip).
Attempt 1 of 5.
Warning: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on 'Mo
mConfigMgr.zip'.
Retrying operation 'Delete' on object filePath (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.zip).
Attempt 2 of 5.
Warning: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on 'Mo
mConfigMgr.zip'.
Retrying operation 'Delete' on object filePath (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.zip).
Attempt 3 of 5.
Warning: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on 'Mo
mConfigMgr.zip'.
Retrying operation 'Delete' on object filePath (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.zip).
Attempt 4 of 5.
Warning: An error was encountered when processing operation 'Delete File' on 'Mo
mConfigMgr.zip'.
Retrying operation 'Delete' on object filePath (MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr.zip).
Attempt 5 of 5.
Error Code: ERROR_FILE_IN_USE
More Information: The file 'MomConfigMgr.zip' is in use.  Learn more at: http://
go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=221672#ERROR_FILE_IN_USE.
Error: The process cannot access 'C:\Users\Declan\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\P
rojects\MomConfigMgr\MomConfigMgr\Deploy\MomConfigMgr.zip' because it is being u
sed by another process.
Error count: 1.
The batch file cannot be found.
```

When run in trial mode, you can see that after it tries to delete the .zip It will deploy the /Scripts and /Views folder.

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your deployment package's location is within the site root. Therefore during the real `sync` operation MSDeploy tries to delete it since those files are not contained inside the package itself.